# validation form - no spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a function which validate the length of the value of a field,

```
function validateName(name) {
  if(name.val().length < 5) {
  }
}
```

I want to check also for the presence of white spaces.
I tried with this but it didn't work:

```
function validateName(name) {
  if(name.val().length < 5 && name.val(" ") < 0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it allowed to have empty spaces at the middle? Something like `A    B` is valid?

Comment: no because it should be a URL . I know now it is name but I am going to use it for urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the code above is that [`$.fn.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) changes behaviour on the basis of the arguments it receives as input; and specifically, it's a *getter* when it's executed without parameters, and a *setter* when it's executed with one parameter.
So this line:

```
name.val(" ")
```

doesn't check for the presence of empty space in the value, but set the value to a single empty space.

There're numerous different approaches to check if a string contains at least an empty space; here I'll go for [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), so that the `validateName` function can be written as:

```
function validateName(name) {
  var val = name.val();
  if (val && val.length < 5 && val.indexOf(" ") < 0) {
    // valid!
  }
}
```

A more expressive approach would be to use [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), but it's also less widely supported by browsers.

```js
function validateName(name) {
  var val = name.val();
  if (val && val.length < 5 && val.indexOf(" ") < 0) {
    console.log("valid", val);
  } else {
    console.log("invalid", val);
  }
}

validateName($('<input value="b" />'));
validateName($('<input value="br" />'));
validateName($('<input value="bru" />'));
validateName($('<input value="brun" />'));
validateName($('<input value="bruno" />'));
validateName($('<input value="b ru" />'));
validateName($('<input />'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, as general advice I wouldn't mess the validation logic with jQuery; that is, it would be better for `validateName` to accept as input a plain string, not a jQuery object representing the input field.

Comment: sorry i miss to call name.val() before .indexOf()

Comment: it works for me... look at my fiddle...
if you write a white space you don't pass the test

Comment: well I will check my code again to see whats wrong, but yes your test is what I want